How to Maintain API URL Stability When Migrating Backend from Vercel to Google Cloud Platform
I’m looking for specific technical solutions to keep the original API URL functioning after migrating my backend from Vercel to Google Cloud. I've considered using a control file or remote config setup, but am unsure how to implement it without impacting users on older app versions. Any advice on achieving this redirection or setup would be much appreciated.
I looked into setting up a control file or remote configuration file that the app could use to dynamically retrieve the current API endpoint. This would let me change the backend URL without requiring an app update. However, I wasn’t sure how to implement it in a way that ensures compatibility for users on older versions.

Here are the some possible ways to migrate the backend:
Firebase Remote Config using Remote Config, you create in-app default values that control the behavior and appearance of your application after you can use Remote Config backend APIs to override in-app default values for all Remote Config API consumers. This will update the endpoint without needing to release a new app version.
API provider is responsible for creating and deploying an API on API Gateway. A single API hosted on API Gateway can be configured to access different backends based on information passed in the request. Update the gateway configuration to point to the new backend URL without affecting older versions.
Implement versioning in your API URL. This will maintain multiple versions of your API and make sure backward compatibility. Versioning  maintains the old API version while transitioning to the new one.
Or Try to Implement URL redirection to ensure that old URLs automatically redirect to the new ones. You can configure it through GCP's URL Map or HTTP(S) Load Balancer. HTTP(S) Load Balancer also manages multiple backend versions and ensures smooth transitions between them.
